# spark stream kafka parallel receiver receive data unbalanced

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, receiver, dstream

I just want try to receive stream data from kafka in parallel.
Here is my code:

```
val myKafkaStream = (1 to numReceivers.toInt).map { i =>
   KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap)
}
```

I run the code on the yarn , the numReceiver is 5,and the code does work.
But the question is only two receivers receive data.
the num-executor is 5,the executor-core is 2

The result:

```
KafkaReveiver-0 : 49637.95 event/sec
KafkaReveiver-1 : 0.0 event/sec
KafkaReveiver-2 : 0.0 event/sec
KafkaReveiver-3 : 49616.85 event/sec
KafkaReveiver-4 : 0.0 event/sec
```

Comment: Please can you post what you have assigned to topicMap

Comment: `val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_,60)).toMap`   and  the topic is "astro_spark"